# How to remove ?domain= from url

Tags: .htaccess

I am really confused now, i have removed index.php through .htaccess, but unable to remove ?domain= from url, i have tried some of the examples:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?domain/?$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^domain/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

And many more, Help me

Answer (score 1):

Add `?` in the end of target URI to strip off query string:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?domain/?$ /$1/? [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^domain/(.*)$ /$1? [L,R=301]
```